# Save more IDs in Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

maybe someone have a Idea? I want to put this in a Cookie with a Save button is that possible?

```
    <td id="dropzoneorg">File from Server</td>
    <td id="dropzoneteil">File from Server</td>
    <td id="dropzoneref">File from Server</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/tvd4bs6v/4/

This is Working good ( i copy this code)

How can i save more Ids? dropzoneorg,dropzoneteil,dropzoneref....

He save now just a dropzoneorg

Comment: First, cookies and localstorage aren't the same thing. Second, localstorage is just a Map, you store anything you want to. In your fiddle, you save your data in the key `List`, just change the key and save anything else?

Comment: Hey, okay i dont know. sorry about my english :) Yes i want to Save everything but dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic/stupid example... That is so basic, I think you have to master and understand the basics.

```
//This part fetches the data from the inputs.
var dropzoneorg = $('#dropzoneorg').html();
var dropzoneteil = $('#dropzoneteil').html();
var dropzoneref = $('#dropzoneref').html();

//This part saves the data fetched to the localstorage, so that you can restore it later.
localStorage.setItem('dropzoneorg', dropzoneorg);
localStorage.setItem('dropzoneteil', dropzoneteil);
localStorage.setItem('dropzoneref', dropzoneref);

//If you want to restore the data from the localStorage to your application
dropzoneref = localStorage.getItem('dropzoneref');

//If you want to put that data back in your form: 
$('#dropzoneref').html(dropzoneref);
```

Comment: Thanks man this shows good but cant used it my problem i never used javascript but i need this script for one projekt https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/tvd4bs6v/3/ something i make wrong

Comment: Please explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish. With the code I gave you, you persist the three values. Your initial question was: how can i save more IDs, but it seems it is not the actual problem.

Comment: Hm Sorry my English is bad, i want to Save the IDs if i make Refresh F5 i want the Files are still inside   I need something like this :  var savein = $('#dropzoneorg').html()|| $('#dropzoneteil').html()||$('#dropzoneref').html();

Comment: I added some example in my answer for each case, hope this helps. If it doesn't, please explain what you want to do, not with code but with words as simple as you can.

Comment: I try to explain. I have Files that i can do with drag and drop to put this in:<td id="dropzoneorg">File Drop</td> than i have a Button(save) he must to Save the Data/Files there are inside. So when i refresh the Site he must show me the Files in the same drop zone. And if i click on Delete Button than he delete my localStorage i hope you can undersand me :)Sorry........ My First code is working but he Save me just one Id this one :<td id="dropzoneorg">File Drop</td> And i want that he save me all Dropzones

Comment: Well, if you use properly the pieces of code above, you should be able to get values from the webpage, store them, restore them and put them back to your webpage! Everything is there!

Comment: i must test :S its a first time and i need javascript just for that... i have test it like that youre code in my https://jsfiddle.net/michiffm/tajbrak9/ but no Chance

Comment: This is not a javascript problem, you need to learn the programmation basics: look at your `restoreContents` function: you override the content of the myList variable. You have three values to handle, but only one variable, that does not make sense. Here the only value restored is `dropzoneref` because it is the last one to be dealt with.